Custom protocol scheme not working in Electron
Using the latest stable Electron (29)
Sample code is taken from the official docs:
import { app, BrowserWindow, protocol, net } from 'electron';

protocol.registerSchemesAsPrivileged([
  {
    scheme: 'foo',
    privileges: {
      bypassCSP: true,
      standard: true,
      secure: true,
      supportFetchAPI: true,
    }
  }
]);

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  console.log("app rdy")
  protocol.handle('foo', (req) => {
    console.log("yo", req.url); // <-- never executed

     return new Response('bad', {
       status: 400,
       headers: { 'content-type': 'text/html' }
     })
  })
})

app.on('ready', () => {
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    width,
    height,
    x,
    y,
    frame: false,
    closable: true,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: `preload.js`,
      nodeIntegration: false,
      nodeIntegrationInSubFrames: false,
      contextIsolation: true,
    },
  });

   win.loadURL(`foo://main.html`);
});

So what is supposed to do - is to register the foo protocol, then load in the main window an url with the foo:// scheme. This should be handled by the foo handler function, but it's not.
The function never runs, and instead some Windows window is opened with a box telling me I need to download some app from the windows store to open "foo" files!? wtf?
So I did some more research and found this function: app.setAsDefaultProtocolClient(protocol) which I assume is supposed to make the electron app be the default app that opens foo:// links..
So after I added app.setAsDefaultProtocolClient('foo') hell ensued and the electron app kept opening new instances of itself continuously until I had to forcibly power down my PC because it become unresponsive.
My guess is that Electron passes any non-http or file urls to Windows for some weird reason, and it doesn't take into account protocol.handle and/or registerSchemesAsPrivileged...
Anyone else facing the same issue?

Did you register the protocol in the Windows registry? Possible programmatically, which would be useful because many "civilians" (for lack of a better term) will find this overwhelming and some of us nerds would be too afraid to screw up in the registry and destroy their machine.

You use both app.on("ready", ...) and app.whenReady(). Which happens earlier? And you register the protocol handler in the .then(...) after the whenReady() promise is fulfilled, does this perhaps also delay it? In other words: Is the foo: URL perhaps loaded before the handler is registered?

Why would i need to register this in windows too? I only want it to work for loadURL inside my app, not for opening links from outside using my app. And the reason is because cookies don't work with local files, so I need to register a new protocol for that!

Its to do with sessions! from: Official docs

A protocol is registered to a specific Electron session object. If you don't specify a session, then your protocol will be applied to the default session that Electron uses. However, if you define a partition or session on your browserWindow's webPreferences, then that window will use a different session and your custom protocol will not work if you just use electron.protocol.XXX

This works:
import { app, BrowserWindow, protocol, session } from 'electron';

const path = require('node:path')
const url = require('url')

protocol.registerSchemesAsPrivileged([
  {
    scheme: 'foo',
    privileges: {
      bypassCSP: true,
      standard: true,
      secure: true,
      supportFetchAPI: true,
    }
  }
]);

app.whenReady().then(() => {

  const partition = 'persist:subdeveloper'
  const ses = session.fromPartition(partition)

  console.log("app rdy")
  ses.protocol.handle('foo', (req) => {
    console.log("yo", req.url); // <-- never executed

     return new Response('bad', {
       status: 400,
       headers: { 'content-type': 'text/html' }
     })
  })

  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ webPreferences: { partition } });

  mainWindow.loadURL(`foo://main.html`);
})

